# A good resource for learning how to analyze circuits using structured approach?

Tags: circuit-analysis, analog

As an electronics beginner, I often have difficulty understanding how some circuits work from reading a diagram. While I understand most components and what they do and how they work, I get totally confused when tracing how they operate together for analog circuits.

I suspect my software engineering background pollutes my perspective. Software executes synchronously, while circuits execute asynchronously. When reading a program, you know where to start and you're always aware of the program state and what happens next. When reading a circuit, however, I often find myself ping ponging from one component to another trying to make sense of it. I often don't know where to start. It usually ends in extreme confusion, mental exhaustion and a long powernap.

Are there any resources for learning how to analyze circuits in a structured way? I am always impressed how some folks here can masticate, digest, and burp out an explanation of a circuit so effortlessly.

Comment: There's a lot of similarities between reading a schematic and reading a sentence written in a natural language. Well designed schematics will mostly have signal flow from left to right, positive supply at the top and ground or negative supply at the bottom, but beyond that you need to learn the "words" that schematics are written in. Learn how to identify configurations of transistors and such as having particular functions. Right now, you know the "letters"; transistors and resistors and op amps and diodes. Learn how those letters come together into words.

Comment: Is there *A good resource for learning how to* read Chinese *using structured approach?*

Comment: @Andyaka  Yes.  You start with primitive glyphs and add them together to form more complex glyphs. Similar to learning to read using phonics. That's one structured approach, albeit not always reliable. The other way is to just memorize the glyphs. This is akin to sight reading where the learner sees the inherent patterns on their own.

Comment: That's how I learnt electronics.

Comment: EE usually starts with two years intense study of math. Piece by piece you earn an understanding of circuit dynamics by learning the mathematics behind and how to use math to model a circuit.

Answer (score -1):

download Douglas Self's book on audio power amplifiers